# How to get coordinates of an object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I want to be able to get the coordinates of an object (e.g. triangle) after it's been translated and rotated, the reason i want to do this is so that later i can do collision detection and calculate the distance between objects using the coordinates. I think I might have to use gluProject but not sure. Also what are the differences between the different coordinate spaces e.g. world, object etc.

I've got some code below it's a circle in the middle of a square, how would i detect when the circle touches one of the edges, i can move it round using the up,down,left, right keys it just changes the x or y coordinates, but i just want to be able to do some basic collision detection and I don't know how to do it.

```
glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

    glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); 
        glVertex3f(-5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();


    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(x, y, -20.0f);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex3f(-5, -5, 10.0f);
    glEnd();

    GLUquadricObj *qobj = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(qobj, GLU_FILL);
    gluSphere(qobj, 1.0f, 20, 20);
    gluDeleteQuadric(qobj);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: I'm assuming your triangle is stored somewhere (an array, etc)... just use that.

Comment: Which OpenGL? (I assume 2.1 or earlier)

Comment: @JoePhillips , that isn't possible if you do translate, rotate and scale, especially if you do layers of these things (as Kos menttons, calling them sword, arm, knight etc). You would be into serious trig etc to be able to "just use that".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Also what are the differences between the different coordinate spaces e.g. world, object etc.

This is mostly a matter of convention, but:

- **Model space** (= local space) is the coordinate space of a specific model, relative to its "center". If you have a file with a model, the coordinates are centered around some point of it (e.g. it's geometrical center, its base, anything actually).
- **Scene space** (= world space) is the coordinate space relative to an arbitrary point of your scene
- **Eye space** (= view space) is the space where the camera is at point `(0,0,0)`, `x` faces right, `y` faces up and `z` faces **out** of the screen (`-z` = deeper)
- **Clip space** is where `(-1,-1,*)` is the bottom left corner of the viewport, `(1,1,*)` is the top right corner of the viewport, and the Z coordinate in (-1,1) indicates just the depth (again smaller Z = deeper). (Fragments
- **Screen space** (= window coordinates) is the same as above, except that the coordinates  are rescaled from `-1..1` to pixel-based values matching the range of the current viewport and depth range.

You transform coordinates from model space to scene space by multiplying (in OpenGL conventions usually left-multiplying) by a **model matrix** (which contains the information on where the model is on the scene). If you have a scene hierarchy, there can be many "stacked" model matrices for an object (placement of the sword relative to an arm, arm relative to a knight, knight relative to the scene).

Then you transform the coordinates to eye space by multiplying by a **view matrix** (usually connected to a "camera" object).

After that, using a **projection matrix** you transform those coords to the screen space, so that OpenGL would map these coords to actual screen pixels (depending on the viewport setting).

Some facts:

- Model and view matrices usually contain translation, rotation and/or scaling, while projection matrix usually contains a perspective transformation, which makes the objects further from the screen appear smaller.
- Old OpenGL (2.x and earlier) required you to put the matrices on two "matrix stacks":

  - GL_MODELVIEW stack which should contain View*Model (or View*Model1*Model2...*ModelN),
  - GL_PROJECTION stack which sould contain only the Projection matrix.

*These could just as well be single matrices, not stacks, but the stack (along with `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`) was introduced to let the programmer "save and load" them easily. Only the "topmost" matrix from each stack is used in calculations.*

The projection matrix is usually created with `gluPerspective` or equivalent. The view matrix can be made with `gluLookAt` (or similarly to model matrices), and the model matrices can be easily assembled using `glTranslate`, `glRotate` and `glScale`.

*(note: OpenGL 3.1+ removed these features, allowing you to use any matrices and any conventions you prefer)*

---

Knowing that:

> I want to be able to get the coordinates of an object (e.g. triangle) after it's been translated and rotated, the reason i want to do this is so that later i can do collision detection and calculate the distance between objects using the coordinates

A reasonable way to calculate all your physics is to do them in **scene space**.

Hence if you have a model (e.g. a triangle mesh), to obtain the position of any its vertex in **scene space**, you need to left-multiply it by only the model's **model matrix** (or in case of the hierarchy, by all its model matrices).

---

About `gluProject`, in case you wondered- it is a convenience method which allows you to multiply a set of coordinates by the current `PROJECTION*MODELVIEW` and performs viewport transformation to see where it would end up in screen space, and `gluUnProject` does the reverse.

Ref: http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm

Comment: What you call screen space is actually **clip space** (although clip space has z in [-1,1]), whereas **screen space** results after viewport transformation and therefore usually is the `[0,w]x[0,h]x[0,1]`-box, which is also what you get from `gluProject` and put into `gluUnProject`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Almost there, but in clip space the near plane is at -1 and the far plane at 1, so it is already `larger z = deeper`.

Comment: If ModelView contains View*Model, how do you obtain just the Model matrix? Is that where glPush/PopMatrix come in? (I'm using OpenGL 4.4 and GLUT.)

Comment: @Lèsemajesté The matrix stack together with `glPush/PopMatrix` has been removed somewhere in OpenGL 3.x, so you'd just declare a `uniform mat4` in your shader and fill it with whatever matrix you need in the client code. If you're using the compatibility profile and OpenGL 2-era builtin `gl_ModelViewMatrix` variable, you can still declare your own `uniform`s on top of that.

Comment: You gave a lot of insight for which I am grateful, but sadly not an actual solution for the OP. There is a proven solution for the OP, but I published it and got an instant down-vote, so I don't see the point in sharing.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kos' answer, keep in mind that **OpenGL is not a scene management library**. It is just a drawing API that draws things onto the screen and then forgets about them. Likewise it doesn't have any understanding of what an "object" is, it only knows triangles and even these it can't remember after they have been drawn. Never wondered why you have to render the whole scene anew each frame?

So to know an object's absolute position in the scene, keep track of the transformations yourself and, well, compute its position from these.

Comment: "keep track of the transformations yourself" .. If you've done several translates and rotates at odd degrees, that's near impossible. Or moreover, you may as well forget the translate and rotate functions and just do it yourself with trig etc, thus always keeping all you coords in one absolute matrix. That way, you can't get your virtual position and the actual position out of sync.

Comment: That sentence is supposed to be understood in such a general sense, yes.

Comment: Thanks 'Chris says Reinstate Monica' ... See my new answer. It is possible to not have to track (with all the tracking sync issues that raises) but my method is a bit of a hack. Ps: Years ago in a previous incarnation, I did indeed scrap the translate and rotate and just did it all myself so effectively all primitives were drawn from absolute xyz vertices. It worked but it was.... "complicated".

Answer (score 0):

mx, my are simply mause cursor coordinates

```
import numpy as np
```

i didnt know about glunproject and recalculate it (open version of glunproject)

```
def CalculateRealCoordinates(mx, my):

    Inverseofmodelviewmatrix = np.linalg.inv(glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX))
    Inverseofprojectionmatrix = np.linalg.inv(glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX))

    WindowCoordinates_x = mx
    WindowCoordinates_y = my

    # glViewport(x, y, w, h)
    glViewports = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)

    NormalizedDeviceCoordinates_x = (WindowCoordinates_x - (
            glViewports[0] + (glViewports[2] / 2))) * (2 / glViewports[2])
    NormalizedDeviceCoordinates_y = (WindowCoordinates_y - (
            glViewports[1] + (glViewports[3] / 2))) * (2 / glViewports[3])

    w = 1
    ClipCoordinates_x = NormalizedDeviceCoordinates_x * w
    ClipCoordinates_y = NormalizedDeviceCoordinates_y * w

    ClipCoordinatesMatrix = [[ClipCoordinates_x],
                             [-ClipCoordinates_y],
                             [0],
                             [0]]

    ClipCoordinatesMatrix = np.array(ClipCoordinatesMatrix)

    EyeCoordinatesMatrix = np.matmul(Inverseofprojectionmatrix, ClipCoordinatesMatrix)

    RealCoordinatesMatrix = np.matmul(Inverseofmodelviewmatrix, EyeCoordinatesMatrix)

    RealCoordinates_x = RealCoordinatesMatrix[0, 0]
    RealCoordinates_y = RealCoordinatesMatrix[1, 0]

    return RealCoordinates_x, RealCoordinates_y
```

builtin gluUnProject version:

```
def CalculateRealCoordinates(mx, my):

    WindowCoordinates_x = mx
    WindowCoordinates_y = my
    WindowCoordinates_z = 0

    RealCoordinates = gluUnProject(WindowCoordinates_x, WindowCoordinates_y, WindowCoordinates_z, glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX), glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX), glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT))

    RealCoordinates_x = RealCoordinates[0]
    RealCoordinates_y = RealCoordinates[1]

    return RealCoordinates_x, RealCoordinates_y
```

and if you want to reverse only MODELVIEW_MATRIX

```
# your projection matrix must be like this -->
# [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

def CalculateRealCoordinates(mx, my):
    Inverseofmodelviewmatrix = np.linalg.inv(glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX))

    WindowCoordinates_x = mx
    WindowCoordinates_y = my

    glViewports = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)

    NormalizedDeviceCoordinates_x = (WindowCoordinates_x - (glViewports[0] + (glViewports[2] / 2))) * (
                2 / glViewports[2])
    NormalizedDeviceCoordinates_y = (WindowCoordinates_y - (glViewports[1] + (glViewports[3] / 2))) * (
                2 / glViewports[3])

    NormalizedDeviceMatrix = [[NormalizedDeviceCoordinates_x],
                              [NormalizedDeviceCoordinates_y],
                              [0],
                              [0]]
    NormalizedDeviceMatrix = np.array(NormalizedDeviceMatrix)

    RealCoordinates = np.matmul(Inverseofmodelviewmatrix, NormalizedDeviceMatrix)
    print("RealCoordinates:", RealCoordinates)

    RealCoordinates_x = RealCoordinates[0, 0]
    RealCoordinates_y = RealCoordinates[1, 0]

    return RealCoordinates_x, -RealCoordinates_y
```